# iPad NSInternalInconsistencyException on UIActionSheet showInView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uiactionsheet

In my universal iPhone/iPad app, I get a crash only on the iPad when I am trying to present an action sheet within a modal view.  It doesn't crash when I am in the main view.  The process goes something like:

(user clicks a button to present the modal view)

```
-(IBAction)showModal:(id)sender {
    modalController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalController animated:YES];
}
```

(then, at a specified time, a function is called which then brings up a UIActionSheet)

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

This gives me the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error on just the iPad? Thanks!

Comment: self.view is nil. You should show us more code ...

Comment: There is a lot of code I don't know what would be relevant to include? The thing is it works on the iPhone, just not the iPad.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  The documentation suggests calling `showFromRect:inView:animated:` on an iPad but not that `showInView:` is unacceptable.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using?:

```
UIActionsheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm"
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                      destructiveButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
```

Comment: Sorry I neglected to include the line before it I already define: 

`UIActionsheet *actionSheet;`